# SQL output query

Tags: sql

[image: INPUT]

[image: REQUIRED OUTPUT]

Hi,

I am trying to convert the SQL table from input to the output format.

**Input file has keys**- Material, Variant, Scale

To reduce the number of rows, scale based pricing is being implemented at my organization. Not sure how do we use input format (image 1) to convert to output format (image 2)

**output table keys**- product, variant, scale_low, scale_high

This is going to reduce the number of pricing records we are going to enter in the system.

Requesting help from anyone who has dealt with this issue in the past.

Comment: People normally kick off about images of code and data.. Strive to use your normal query tools to prepare scripts for us that we can run to temporarily create your table and data. Few people are willing to write these things out by hand from a picture, especially when they're already on your machine and having the software script them up is a few mouse clicks (and they're then easier to get into your question than images are). Desired output as an image is tolerable, if a bit of a waste of bandwidth..

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't know why SO doesn't have canned-text comment templates, it would save us all so much time and trouble - and the templates could be politely and (\*gasp\*) even compassionately and helpfully written so we don't come across as old curmudgeons.

Comment: @CaiusJard (and a note to self) I just found this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments via [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310111/how-do-i-use-canned-comments) - now I just need it in a drop-down list on-page

Comment: Oh, the number of times I've thought about writing some wrapper website for SO that solves things like that, or even a browser extension for all the advanced functionality I keep dreaming up but getting slapped down on meta for suggesting.. one small bonus about using an iPhone to do most my posting is the keyboard has macros so I can write eg imgofcode and press space and whoosh, it expands to a twenty seven line lecture .. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could just take the min and max values like so:

```
Select product, variant, 
min(scale) as scale_low, max(scale) as scale_high, 
Min(CondValue) as low_amt, Max(CondValue) as high_amt
group by product, variant
order by product, variant;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have variant from 1-150 and 9999999. I need to group the variant based on- 1-10, 11-30, 31-50, 51-150 and 150+. If I use min and max scale, how will I be able to group it?

Comment: You could handle that several ways, you could create a temp table out of the original data, you could turn this into a CTE to handle your multiple groupings, you could create a real table out of it so you can do further modifications to it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider doing it like this:

```
WITH bands AS (
  SELECT 1 as lo, 10 as hi 
  UNION ALL SELECT 11, 30
  UNION ALL SELECT 31, 50
  UNION ALL SELECT 51, 150
  UNION ALL SELECT 151, 999999
)
SELECT
  Material, Variant, Lo, Hi, MIN(Value), MAX(Value)
FROM
  t
  INNER JOIN bands ON t.Scale BETWEEN lo and hi
GROUP BY Material, Variant, Lo, Hi
```

Or i'd turn that bands into a real table so I could just tweak them without having to rewrite my sql